# Training the same model on the same data yielding extremely different test accuracy

Tags: keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am getting very inconsistent test accuracies from my model but cannot figure out why.

I was trying to benchmark some TensorFlow/Keras stuff and noticed my results were unreliable. Not the timing, but the test accuracy of the model. On some runs, the model would achieve a test accuracy = 0.65, and sometimes it would achieve only 0.35. Same architecture, same optimizer trained on the same dataset, same everything.

I tried to remove most sources of randomness, such as using the same numpy rng seed, TensorFlow rng seed, resetting the TensorFlow backend between runs, and using the same seed for shuffling the dataset, etc. The issue persists.

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

[Here is a reproducible example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b2DZaAIjqqXDlQ_uJyinVxOn1z_cbAoT?usp=sharing) on Google Colab,
but the issue also happens locally with different versions of Python, TensorFlow, and Cuda/Cudnn.

And [here is the dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UXJOv9MJ7bu_0woiVVp0BmcnfDzo0hpf/view?usp=sharing) I am using. It is just CIFAR-10 with the training partition split into train and validation.

edit:
It appears the issue is caused my some interaction between `.shuffle` and `batch`, more specifically to their parameters `buffer_size`, `reshuffle_each_iteration`, and `drop_remainder`.
The following combination appears to avoid the problem (but incurs in large memory usage):

```
dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=dataset.cardinality().numpy(),
                reshuffle_each_iteration=False,
                seed=rng_seed)
        .batch(batch_size=batch_size,
               drop_remainder=True)
```

Comment: i can't access the notebook (maybe others can?). anyway, you're saying if you run on the same machine, environment, pytorch, cuda, etc. versions, with even the same random seed, the accuracies come out totally differently? maybe your optimizer contains a random component and thus finds different local optima of the loss function. try varying values for the learning rate, at some values the training might be unstable. you could also do N times M runs and report the best accuracy that you find amongst m runs. if the best accuracies agree well, this might indicate randomness being the cause.

Comment: Woops, I didn't use the "insert link" feature correctly. Please try again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For speed, in all following experiments, I fixed epoch to`1`.

One of the most violent solution is adding the following 2 lines before you building model, which does not need any other changes and support `random`:

```
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(some_seed)
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
```

i.e.:

```py
def why_u_inconsistent():
    # tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    # tf.random.set_seed(42)
    # np.random.seed(42)
    tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)
    tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
    train, val, test = get_train_val_test()
    model = get_model()
    model.fit(train, validation_data=val, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    scores = model.evaluate(test, verbose=0)
    for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, scores):
        print(f"test {name}: {value}")
```

the output is (You'll be satisfied because they're exactly the same):

```
run: 0
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 3.872633934020996
test accuracy: 0.1818999946117401
=====
run: 1
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 3.872633934020996
test accuracy: 0.1818999946117401
=====
run: 2
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 3.872633934020996
test accuracy: 0.1818999946117401
=====
run: 3
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 3.872633934020996
test accuracy: 0.1818999946117401
=====
run: 4
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 3.872633934020996
test accuracy: 0.1818999946117401
```

P.S. When setting random seed, we should use [`tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed), which including `random`,`numpy.random` and `tensorflow.random`. They actually use three different single instance of random, i.e., their random seeds do not interact each other, but did influence our codes because we use them inevitably. Of course, it can be set separately, `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed` is just a convenient way. Unfortunately, your original code did not set the seed of the basic module `random`.

Then, I checked if data pipeline's output must be the same across each `run_nr`. I writed each batch's `reduce_mean` into `csv` file to compare each `run_nr`'s output, and found they had no difference at all. So here, we can draw the probelm as [`determinism`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism?hl=en) problem and I have explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403997/17357963)

When it comes to your problem, I find a better explanation, i.e., 2 key point `momentum` and `learning_rate` make your algorithm suffers from `determinism` problem. Provided we do not use `tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism`, any algorithm is uncertain in the last few bits of precision (it may be caused by `cuda` or `TensorFloat-32` dtype), but `momentum` accumulate the uncertainty error and `learning_rate` amplify the error. If we use
`SGD`(Not that you must to use it) optimizer without `momentum` like this:

```py
...
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.001)
    model.compile(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
...
def why_u_inconsistent(index):
    tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)
    # tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
    train, val, test = get_train_val_test()
    
    model = get_model()
    model.fit(train, validation_data=val, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    scores = model.evaluate(test, verbose=0)
    for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, scores):
        print(f"test {name}: {value}")
...
```

the output after `1` epoch will like the following, where outputs are very close:

```
run: 0
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 2.20281720161438
test accuracy: 0.1808999925851822
=====
run: 1
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 2.202397346496582
test accuracy: 0.1809999942779541
=====
run: 2
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 2.2010912895202637
test accuracy: 0.18019999563694
=====
run: 3
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 2.200165271759033
test accuracy: 0.18230000138282776
=====
run: 4
Found 42500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 7500 files belonging to 10 classes.
Found 10000 files belonging to 10 classes.
test loss: 2.2025880813598633
test accuracy: 0.18019999563694
=====
```

So let's draw a better conclusion:

1. Use `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(some_seed)` control all random behavior is needed
2. Optimize the algorithm as much as possible to mitigate the impact of calculation accuracy. That is, let the algorithm not produce or accumulate small errors in accuracy. There are many adjustable keys, not only the `optimizer` or the `optimizer`'s parameters, but also other stuff such as `bacth_size`, `gradient_clip`, `gradient_norm` etc.
3. Use `tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism` if you want to get completely consistent reproducible results and accept its side effects(deceleration).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Sadly, I am not yet able to read the language of the bug link. I created a issue on GitHub and will try your suggestions (2) and (3). I am curious about the side effects of enable_op_determinism; does the affect the performance (training time) too much? And what do you mean by no cascading in your suggestion (1)? Could please elaborate? And thanks again.

Comment: I noticed that using shuffle(..., reshuffle_each_iteration=True) yield terrible results. And that using shuffle(dataset.cardinality().numpy()) yields great results.

Comment: @Trauer I have made some extra tests, located the problem and simplified my answer above. It must be a `determinism` problem and the lightest way here is to adjust your optimizer and learning rate to mitigate the accumulation of uncertainty errors.

Comment: I updated the question to include a way to workaround the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you are having 2 problems which are causing the different results for each run:

1. Using GPU
2. Using `tf.data.AUTOTUNE`

**Solution for 1:**
Switch your runtime in Colab to "None"

[image] [image]

**Solution for 2:**
Change your return from `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` to afixed BatchSize (e.g.128):

```
train.prefetch(128),
val.prefetch(128),
test.prefetch(128),
```

You can also see my adaption of [your code here.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rXTny9XepPTcCBhuVDyuMXNmgqKMppwP?usp=sharing)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but not using a GPU is pretty much impossible for my real workarounds. I will try fixing the prefetch and post the results here.